# Pass and return OpenCv Mat object with JNI

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, mat

I would like to write a function in JNI like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_datumdroid_android_ocr_simple_HoughLine_nativeDetectLine
```

(JNIEnv * jenv, jclass, jstring fileInput, jobject mat)

The Java interface would be :

```
nativeDetectLine( String fileInput, Mat mat);
```

Now I want to pass the Mat to JNI and change its value.

Can anyone give me a tutorial or guide? 
Specifically how work with jobjects.

Answer (score 1):

http://answers.opencv.org/question/12271/can-the-java-interface-pass-a-mat-to-opencvs-c/

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial2_Tutorial2Activity_FindFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong  addrGray, jlong addrRgba)
{
    Mat& mGr  = *(Mat*)addrGray;
    Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
    ... do stuff with the Mat objects ...
}
```

Comment: first cast the jlong to Mat* , then dereference it.