# Out Of Memory crash in JNI using OpenCV OnCameraFrame

Tags: c++, opencv, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault, orb

I call a native method in my `OnCameraFrame` that checks current frame's keypoints and tries to find good matches with keypoints of template images, calculates which indexed image has the most good matches and returns the index. (it's an object recognition App). Problem is it works really slow (3-4 fps, taking 0.3 seconds to finish this method) and after 10-20frames, it crashes with `SIGSEGV code=1` error. I realise this is probably an Out Of Memory problem, but can't figure which part in the code eats all the RAM. Hope you can help.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL  Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial2_Tutorial2Activity_processImage(
    JNIEnv* env, jlong frameAddress) {


Mat& image = *(Mat*) frameAddress;

cv::OrbFeatureDetector detector(100);
cv::OrbDescriptorExtractor extractor;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> queryKeypoints;

detector.detect(image, queryKeypoints);

Mat queryDescriptors;
extractor.compute(image, queryKeypoints, queryDescriptors);

queryDescriptors.convertTo(queryDescriptors, CV_32F);

vector < DMatch > matches;
flannMatcher.match(queryDescriptors, matches);


double max_dist = 0;
double min_dist = 100;

std::vector < DMatch > good_matches;

for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    if (matches[i].distance <= max(2 * min_dist, 0.02)) {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}

int * gmatchIndexes;
gmatchIndexes = new int[good_matches.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
    gmatchIndexes[i] = -1;
}
for (int kk = 0; kk < good_matches.size(); kk++) {

    gmatchIndexes[good_matches[kk].imgIdx]++;

}


int maxIdx = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
    if (gmatchIndexes[i] > maxIdx) {
        maxIdx = i;
    }
}

int* p_answer = &maxIdx;
int answer = *p_answer;

//if (gmatchIndexes[maxIdx] > 2) {
image.release();
vector<DMatch>().swap(matches);
vector<DMatch>().swap(good_matches);
delete[] gmatchIndexes;
queryDescriptors.release();

return answer;

}
```

**EDIT**: added releases/deletes to my code, but now i get errors like  `@@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree` and `:0: gralloc_module_lock: Cannot lock buffer ID=55438 before register (0x0)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use frameAddress in that way. Instead you should use GetByteArrayElements/ReleaseByteArrayElements to get actual pointer to your data (and construct Mat of appropriate type). For example: http://ruckus.tumblr.com/post/18055652108/writing-a-basic-image-filter-in-android-using-ndk

Comment: I saw an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752820/pass-and-return-opencv-mat-object-with-jni using the way i used passing a Mat. But i will try another method of passing, even though i don't think this is what's causing the crash

Comment: I'm sorry, I always create Mat inside JNI and never used getNativeObjAddr before.